# How to use filter when creating calculated column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Filter cannot be used in calculated columns, then how can I simply create a column in DAX that would pick up a value based on maximum `claimID` and maximum `DateCreated` ?

[image]

**The result should be like this:**

[image]

Comment: Why 100? It doesn't appear to correspond to the latest `DateCreated`? You only take nonzero and there aren't further nonzero values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters can be used in calculated columns. Just don't expect them to be responsive to slicers. In this case, it is probably more efficient computationally not to use a `FILTER` function in favor of simple `CALCULATE` arguments:

```
TotalIncurredMaxDate =
VAR MaxDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table1[DateCreated] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table1, Table1[ControlNo], Table1[ClaimID] ),
        Table1[TotalIncurred] > 0
    )
RETURN
    IF ( Table1[DateCreated] = MaxDate, Table1[TotalIncurred], 0 )
```

Comment: Great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Calculated columns have a "row context" of the current row, and no filter context, as they are calculated during model load, before any filters are applied.  But you can create filters in your calculation.  EG

```
TotalIncurredMaxDate = 
    var claimId = Table1[ClaimID]
    var controlNo = Table1[ControlNo]

    var maxDate = calculate(
        max(Table1[DateCreated]), 
        filter (
          all (Table1), 
          Table1[ClaimID]=claimId
          && Table1[ControlNo] = controlNo
          && Table1[TotalIncurred] > 0
        )
    )

    var retval = if(Table1[DateCreated] = maxDate, Table1[TotalIncurred], 0)

    return retval
```