# Need formula to apply in power bi report

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

[image]I need to add one calculated column in power bi dax. In my excel data there is month end column as shown in table.
[image: Snap of report]

As you can see, W05 is last week of 01/2020 (Report Month), so month end is Y, for rest it is N. Same way, W09 is last week of 02/2020 (Report month), month end= Y. rest is N. Can you help me with the formula I can use in power bi to poplulate end month (N or Y)?

[image: Measure output][image: Measure output]

Comment: This is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this following **measure**-

```
is_last_week = 

var current_report_week = MIN(your_table_name[report week])
var current_minth_max_report_week =
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[report week]),
    ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[report month])
)

RETURN 
IF(
    current_minth_max_report_week = current_report_week,
    "Y",
    "N"
)
```

For **Custom Column**, use this below code-

```
is_last_week = 

var current_report_week = your_table_name[report week]
var current_month_max_report_week =
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[report week]),
    ALLEXCEPT(your_table_name,your_table_name[report month])
)

RETURN 
IF(
    current_month_max_report_week = current_report_week,
    "Y",
    "N"
)
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: I have applied formula - = var current_Report_Week = MIN(Incident[Report Week]) var current_minth_max_report_week = CALCULATE(MAX(Incident[Report Week]), ALLEXCEPT(Incident, Incident[Report Month])) Return IF(current_minth_max_report_week = current_Report_Week,"Y","N") ............ But in output, I'm getting only N for all data.

Comment: using Measure or Custom Column?

Comment: Using new column

Comment: This code is for Measure. Try with a measure, but if column is a requirement, tell me.

Comment: Sure, will definitely accept the answer and vote. I have added picture for measure. Still getting only N, for last week,42 it is Y .. and rest 1 to 41 is N.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223141/discussion-between-r-r-and-kiran-patel).